# git status проблема

Tags: git, консоль

Почему git после команды gid add . выводит:

```
error: open("cd .."): No such file or directory
error: unable to index file cd ..fatal: adding files failed
```

и `Untracked files: cd ..` [image: s]
p.s. только начал работу с консолью, до этого использовал десктопную версию.

Comment: `git clean -xf`

Comment: А если интересно как так вышло, то вангую, что вы закопипастили с чьего-то примера из интернета, где была строка вида `> cd ..`.

Comment: @0andriy λ git clean -xf
fatal: Cannot lstat 'cd ..': No such file or directory выдал такое

Comment: Ну даже не знаю. Скажите такое `stat "cd .."; rm -f "cd .."`.

Comment: @0andriy λ stat "cd .."; rm -f "cd .."
  File: cd ..
  Size: 1167            Blocks: 4          IO Block: 65536  regular file
Device: 26331188h/640881032d    Inode: 6192449487640234  Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (197609/   rafae)   Gid: (197609/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2018-05-30 23:14:11.752736500 +0300
Modify: 2018-05-30 22:59:57.726284600 +0300
Change: 2018-05-30 22:59:57.726284600 +0300
 Birth: 2018-05-30 22:59:52.177927600 +0300

Comment: Ну, так *rm -f* удалил его? Теперь всё в порядке?

Comment: Когда задаете вопросы про консоль, указывайте в тегах операционную систему, это ускорит нахождение ответа.